# A representation problem of the universal enveloping algebra of a graded nilpotent Lie algebra

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Assume we work over $\mathbb C$.

Let $\mathfrak n$ be a finitely dimensional nilpotent Lie algebra. Assume there is an $\mathbb N_+$-grading on $\mathfrak n$, i.e. there exists integers $0<w_1<\cdots<w_l$ and $\mathfrak n=\bigoplus_{i=1}^l\mathfrak n_i$, satisfying $[\mathfrak n_i,\mathfrak n_{i'}]\subset\mathfrak n_{i''}$ if $w_i+w_{i'}=w_{i''}$. One can think that this grading comes from an toric action $\mathbb C^*\to\mathrm{Aut}(\mathfrak n)$, with all weights $>0$. I'd like to call $w_i$'s the *weights* of $\mathfrak n$.

Let $\mathrm{U}(\mathfrak n)$ be the universal enveloping algebra (UEA). Then it has an induced grading: if $\xi_1\in\mathfrak n_{i_1},\cdots,\xi_k\in\mathfrak n_{i_k}$, then $\xi_1\cdots\xi_k\in\mathrm{U}(\mathfrak n)$ has weight $w_{i_1}+\cdots+w_{i_k}$. For any $L>0$, denote by $\mathrm U(\mathfrak n)_{>L}$ the span of vectors of weights $>L$, and $\mathrm U(\mathfrak n)_{\leq L}$ similarly. Then $\mathrm U(\mathfrak n)_{>L}$ is a two-sided ideal for any $L>0$, and $\mathrm U(\mathfrak n)_{\leq L}\cong\mathrm U(\mathfrak n)/\mathrm U(\mathfrak n)_{>L}$ is a finitely dimensional quotient algebra.

Consider the $\mathrm U(\mathfrak n)$-representation
$$W=\bigwedge^{\dim\mathfrak n_1}\mathrm{U}(\mathfrak n)_{\leq w_1}\otimes\cdots\otimes\bigwedge^{\dim\mathfrak n_l}\mathrm U(\mathfrak n)_{\leq w_l}$$
There is a special one-dimensional space
$$V=\bigwedge^{\dim\mathfrak n_1}\mathfrak n_1\otimes\cdots\otimes\bigwedge^{\dim\mathfrak n_l}\mathfrak n_l$$

I want to show that there exists $\alpha\in W$ satisfying:

- $\mathfrak n_l.\alpha=V$ for the subalgebra $\mathfrak n_l$ of maximal weight $w_l$;
- $\mathrm U(\mathfrak n)_{=w_l}.\alpha=V$, where $\mathrm{U}(\mathfrak n)_{=w_l}$ is the subspace of $\mathrm U(\mathfrak n)$ of weight $w_l$.

It is easy to check when $l=1$ or $l=2$. When $l=2$, let $\xi^{(1)}_1,\cdots,\xi^{(1)}_{r_1}$ be a basis of $\mathfrak n_1$ and $\xi^{(2)}_1,\cdots,\xi^{(2)}_{r_2}$ be a basis of $\mathfrak n_2$. Then $$\alpha=w_2\big(\xi^{(1)}_1\wedge\cdots\wedge\xi^{(1)}_{r_1}\big)\otimes\big(1\wedge\xi^{(2)}_2\wedge\cdots\wedge\xi^{(2)}_{r_2}\big)-w_1\sum_{j=1}^{r_1}\big(\cdots\wedge\xi^{(1)}_{j-1}\wedge 1\wedge\xi^{(1)}_{j+1}\wedge\cdots\big)\otimes\big(\xi^{(1)}_j\wedge\xi^{(2)}_2\wedge\cdots\wedge\xi^{(2)}_{r_2}\big)$$ is a solution. I would like to believe this is true in general.

The question comes when I tried to take a blowing-up to achieve the condition ``ss=s'' described in [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.00340). The route from the paper to this question is not very straightforward. However I think the question itself is interesting.

Thanks for any comments.

Comment: It sounds more natural to assume $w_i=i$, and define weight as $i$ such that $\mathfrak{n}_i\neq 0$.

Comment: @YCor Yes, indeed. Nothing essential changes if we just think of $\mathbb C^*\to\mathrm{Aut}(\mathfrak n)$. This $\mathbb C^*$ induces an action on $\mathrm{U}(\mathfrak n)$, and $\mathrm{U}(\mathfrak n)_{>L}$ defined in both ways coincide.